# C# When Assemblies are referenced in the Web.config, where does it look?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have an assembly that apparently has server credentials hard coded into the DLL. Those credentials have since changed. My assemblies are listed as:

```
<assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="XYZ.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96AD35993B90AC04"/>
    <add assembly="XYZ.DAL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=F38AD7B1AAE72AF0"/>
            <add assembly="XYZ.Universal, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=F38AD7B1AAE72AF0"/>
            <add assembly="XYZ.Security, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=F38AD7B1AAE72AF0"/>
            <add assembly="XYZ.Roles, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=F38AD7B1AAE72AF0"/>
            <add assembly="XYZ.Configuration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9BA321F98F0715B4"/>
            </assemblies>
```

I have several copies of the XYZ.DAL on my C drive, as it is used in various projects. How do I know precisely which DDL file my project is using so I can explode that DLL and see what is going on with the server credentials ? I would assume that it would look in the projects BIN file, but It is empty. I am assuming that it is using one of the copies on the DLL, but which one ?

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
       [Exception: Unable to Open Connection
```

Server=XXXSQLDEV;Database=XXXX.NET;UID=XXXAdmin;PWD=XXX
Login failed for user 'EIISAdmin'.]
   ITT.DAL.SQLHelpers.MSSQLHelper.StartExecuteReader(CommandType cmdType, String cmdText, DbParameter[] cmdParams) +951
   ITT.DAL.Universal.PersonDAL.Get(String lanname) +210
   PropertyUploader._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\eric.dahlenburg\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Property.NET\Updates\Default.aspx.cs:25
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

Based on the Stack trace, what do I filter on?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: You can start by using Windows Resource Monitor on Disk tab, filtering by your process.

Comment: In most cases: Bin folder, then GAC.

Comment: Can you dumb it down a little ?  I found Windows Resource monitor, but how do I filter and on what do I filter ?

Comment: Here is my Stack Trace:    [Exception: Unable to Open Connection
Server=XXXSQLDEV;Database=XXX.NET;UID=XXXAdmin;PWD=XXX
Login failed for user 'EIISAdmin'.]
   ITT.DAL.SQLHelpers.MSSQLHelper.StartExecuteReader(CommandType cmdType, String cmdText, DbParameter[] cmdParams) +951
   ITT.DAL.Universal.PersonDAL.Get(String lanname) +210
   PropertyUploader._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\eric.dahlenburg\Documents\Visual Studio 2010

Comment: If you have more information to add, please *edit* your question. Don't dump code or stack traces in the comments

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx `fuslogvw.exe` (shipped with .net) generates reports where fusion the assembly loader of .net has looked in order to find your assemblies.

Comment: I have changed the Fusion log setting to several different log setting and nothing is generated when I run the app in Visual Studio's

Comment: Unless you need all those old copies, I'd delete them all.  If you still see this issue, the DLL is coming from the GAC.  Otherwise, the exception should tell you where it looked when it fails to find a copy.  There are tools that will tell you from where it loaded a dll, but do you really care?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .Net, you will see assemblies loaded from the following locations in this order:

1. GAC
2. Folder where the application is running from (your BIN folder)
3. If you are loading any native assemblies, then the %PATH% comes into play.

More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720133.aspx).

Comment: O.K., I fixed it, but could use some background info...  I found a file called machine.config at the path: ...Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/CONFIG/  and found the wrong connection strings and corrected them. It now works. What exactly did I change and why don't I see it in Solution Explorer ?

Comment: The machine.config file contains settings that apply to the entire computer for a given version of .Net; you'll find them located at \%Windoows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[Framework Version]\CONFIG\machine.config - in essence, by changing that setting in that config file, you've now changed it for all applications that are running on that version of .Net on that machine.

Comment: So that machine.config  file is not auto generated ? I know that if I delete the GAC, it will rebuild from the DLL's. I'm assuming that the CONFIG\machine.config file is a permanent file in Windows. Is  that why I don't see it in my Application in Vis. Studio's

Comment: No, its not auto generated. Think of it more as the config for the .Net framework at that version level. Not sure what you mean by delete the GAC, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The GAC contains all available DLL's on your system. When referencing a DLL it will first check the GAC and then the current BIN folder if the DLL was not found in the GAC.

[For more information regarding GAC look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that it looks in the GAC *first* and then the folder where the executable is run (if running under the debugger would be the bin folder).

Comment: Thought so to so I added it @James